# How to make this lighting effect in cocos2d-x

Tags: shader, cocos2d-x, game-engine, lighting

How do I create this lighting effect in Cocos2d-x ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUHQr.png)

Comment: You need shaders. You can find some examples in cocos2d-x tests.

Answer (score 0):

You better be more specific, about what exactly you want.

Some links may help:

- [Cocos2dx 3D docs - Light](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/3D_Graphics#Light)
- [Texture Packer Lighting tutorial](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/lighting-demo-cocos2d-x)
- [Code Project for tutorial above](https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/cocos2d-x-dynamic-lighting)
- Similar QA at cocos-forum [#1](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/adding-lights-in-cocos2d-x/12896/8) [#2](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/howto-dynamic-light/21411)

If its not what you want, be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://github.com/wantnon2/EffectNodes-for-cocos2dx

There are few other useful effects that you can use.